# Kivy: is it possible to trigger events with class level (not instance) Properties?

Tags: python, properties, kivy

Consider following code. I would like to update multiple widget instances when *prefix* changes. As it is the same for all the instances it seems efficient to store/update it only once on class level (so that when instance does not have its own *self.prefix*, it will automatically refer to class level *prefix* attribute)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

import random

kivy_lang = '''
<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        id: my_button
        text: 'increase indice'
<MyLabel>:
    on_prefix: self.text = self.prefix +':'+ self.indice
    on_indice: self.text = self.prefix +':'+ self.indice

'''
class MyLabel(Label):
    prefix = StringProperty('1')
    indice = StringProperty('0')
    pass

class MainWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_label1 = MyLabel()
        self.my_label2 = MyLabel()
        self.add_widget(self.my_label1)
        self.add_widget(self.my_label2)
        self.ids.my_button.bind(on_press=self.my_method)


    def my_method(self,*args,**kwargs):
        MyLabel.prefix = str(random.randint(0,9))
        self.my_label1.indice = str(int(self.my_label1.indice) + 1)
        # my_label2 would also be updated if its 'indice' got changed as below
        # self.my_label2.indice = str(int(self.my_label2.indice) + 2)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kivy_lang)
        return MainWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

As from the python side this seems right, from Kivy side it looks like kivy has problem recognising when prefix got changed (my_label1 only gets updated because *indice* was also updated and *on_indice* is triggered).

Is there a way to get 'class level Property' *prefix* change to trigger *on_prefix* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible directly, but you could mimic that functionality with `AliasProperty` and another property stored, say, on `App`. As long as the instance of `MyLabel` hasn't changed `prefix`, the value set for `App` is used (and automatically updated). Once `prefix` is set on an instance, `_my_prefix` is not `None`, and will be used to retrieve the value for `prefix`.

Change the `<MyLabel>` rule to

```
<MyLabel>:
    _prefix: app.prefix
    text: self.prefix +':'+ self.indice
```

And change the python code to

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    indice = StringProperty('0')
    _prefix = StringProperty('')
    _my_prefix = StringProperty(None)

    def get_prefix(self):
        if self._my_prefix is None:
            return self._prefix
        else:
            return self._my_prefix
    def set_prefix(self, value):
        self._my_prefix = value

    prefix = AliasProperty(get_prefix, set_prefix, bind=('_prefix', '_my_prefix'))
```

[...]

```
def my_method(self,*args,**kwargs):
    App.get_running_app().prefix = str(random.randint(0,9))
    self.my_label1.indice = str(int(self.my_label1.indice) + 1)
    if int(self.my_label1.indice) == 2:
        self.my_label2.prefix = 'changed'
```

[...]

```
class MyApp(App):
    prefix = StringProperty('1')
```

Comment: nice, 2 things in one go! (I also wanted to ask how to use AliasProperty at some point as I didn't quite catch it from the docs) :)